# The Entity you are trying to import is not the same as the one existing in the database even though it has the same name

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

when trying to import customizations for a specific entity I get an error saying that I can't reuse system queries for a custom entity.
The error in the title appears in the detailed CRM trace:
`Could not import a Saved Query {C9771189-0CB3-E111-A93D-00505699001D} for ObjectTypeCode 10010 because this is a system Saved Query. The Entity you are trying to import is not the same as the one existing in the database even though it has the same name.`

the id of the query is the one in the *source* customizations.

Both the source and target entities seem to have the exact same queries, with the same names.

Google hasn't been able to offer much on this.
Can anyone shed any light on the subject?

Comment: is the entity type code the same? (i.e. contact and account are 2 and 1 respectively)

Comment: yes, they are. forgot to mention that...

Comment: Can you enable tracing and post the relevant bits here?

Comment: Does the import work if you manually cut out the offending `savedquery` node from your solutions xml or does it just push the problem to the next query? (i.e. is this an entity issue or a query issue).

Answer (score 0):

Is your source environment upgraded from v3.0? If so have you applied the hotfix (or latest rollup) mentioned in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948043/en-gb) to *both* servers?

Comment: it isn't. I've tried this anyway, and it didn't seem to make any difference.. :(